# Show the value in textbox in the parent form, of a cell selected of the gridview in the child form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, textbox

This is my code:
IN Parent form:

```
public void tokenform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       tbvarchecker.Text = HelpForm.code;
    }
   private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        HelpForm help = new HelpForm();
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F2)
        {               
            help.Show();               
        }
    }
    public void setvalues(string cd)
    {
        tbvarchecker.Text = cd;
        label10.Text = cd;
    }

  Child Form code:
     private void dgv(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = dgvshowallfields.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        code = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        code1 = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void HelpForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        tokenform tkf = new tokenform();
       tkf.setvalues(code);
        tkf.setvalues(code1);
        tkf.tokenform_Load(sender,e);

    }

    //private void HelpForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    tkf.setvalues(code);
    //}
```

This code is declared as public static string code, while the code1 is just string.
I have also checked through breakpoints and the value reaches the function in Parent form function set values but still, I couldn't show it in the textbox.
Guys can anyone help me out.....??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, pass the parent form to your `Show()` call.

Change:

```
help.Show();
```

To:

```
help.Show(this);
```

Then, in the child form, you can cast the `.Owner` property to your parent form type and call its methods:

```
private void HelpForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    tokenform tkf = this.Owner as tokenform;
    if (tkf != null) 
    {
        tkf.setvalues(code);
        tkf.setvalues(code1);
        tkf.tokenform_Load(sender,e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, bro this helped but can you explain what I was doing wrong and why couldn't I show this value earlier....??

Comment: In your FormClosed() event, you were creating a new instance of tokenform.  That instance you were trying to use was simply invisible and not the same instance as the one you see on your screen.